# How to fix error in installing pyinstaller on mac?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I am trying to install `pyinstaller` for converting python project to an executable file, I am getting an error related to `altgraph`. I don't know what is the problem?

[image]

Comment: what's result after try pip install pyinstaller instead of pip3?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty late but I had the exact same issue on macOS Sierra. I fixed it by calling

```
pip install pyinstaller --user
```

Solved everything.

Answer (score 1):

Seems similar to the issue ,

https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/issues/11

Try the below snippet

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( pip freeze ); do
    sudo pip uninstall -y $i
done
```

Comment: How are you trying to install the packages ? 1. Create a Virtual Environment and then try to install the packages 2. When you have both versions of python 3+ and 2.7 , There might be a problem in mac . As mac has a Pre installed python 2.7 version . try to create a virtual environment and then install the required packages

Comment: NO, nothing is happening. I did try to install pyinstaller in a Virtual Environment.

Comment: Its installation process stops over here :

Comment: Installing collected packages: altgraph, macholib, pyinstaller
  Found existing installation: altgraph 0.10.2
    Uninstalling altgraph-0.10.2:

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```

and remember using `pyInstaller` command to convert to an executable file instead of `pyinstaller` command.

Hope it helps.